# Animation Nodes - curve and objects

Tags: animation, node-editor, bezier-curves, animation-nodes

How can I distribute objects along a curve with animation nodes?

AN 2.1
Blender 2.8

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Did you check the documentation on the [Get Spline Samples](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/spline/get_spline_samples.html) node?

Comment: Thank you! Yes but there is no, get spline samples node with the version im using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Get Spline Samples* node was replaced by the *Evaluate Range* option in the *Evaluate Spline*. This option can be enabled by pressing the button next to the parameter type menu.

[image: Node Tree]